# CSS animation and child elements

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

I am working on updating a legacy html/css app where a lot of functionality depends on flashing divs at the right times.  Flashing is currently done by adding and removing a class with different `color` and `background-color` in a function with `setTimeout`. It currently looks like this:

```
.attention {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
}
```

This class is toggled with a `setTimeout` every 0.5s. This is is very ineffective. I want to replace this with animation, which in itself is very simple:

```
@keyframes flashing-red {
    50% {
        background-color: red;
        color: white;
    }
}

.attention {
    animation: flashing-red 1s step(1) infinite;
}
```

This works perfectly fine, however there is a complication in that the div contains other elements, e.g. child `div` with an icon.  Specifically, the HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="block">
    <div class="block-icon"></div>
</div>
```

And the CSS for the `icon` is defined like this:

```
.block .block-icon {
    background-image: url(sprites.png) no-repeat 0 -110px;
}

.block.attention .block-icon {
    background-image: url(sprites.png) no-repeat 0 -130px;
}
```

As you can see, the icon changes when the `attention` is being added.  When the flashing was achieved by adding-removing class `attention`, the icon was changing along with the background colour.  However with the animation, the background is changing, while the class is always there.  Therefore the icon does not change as it should.

How can I get the icon to change according to the background colour?  I can, of course, define its own keyframes animation, however there are more elements than just this icon and I'm concerned that the multiple animation will not be perfectly in sync.

I really don't want to keep the timers, as the effect is used throughout the app and I at times end up with up to 100 timeouts active and triggering every half a second.

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Why using 100 timeouts when you could use 1 per page, You apply some `example`  class to all elements you want animated, then you go throuh those elements every 0.5 seconds and toggle `attention` class on them. It's easy to do with pure js, and hopefully pretty effective, if there is no css solution.

Comment: @MarkoMackic Because 100 timeouts can be 10 or 50 or 73 milliseconds apart.  The nature of the app requires tracking time to milliseconds - rounding to the nearest second is not an option. In addition, I want to eliminate these timeouts completely.

Comment: I don't think you understood me.

Comment: @MarkoMackic I don't think you understood me. Let's say I need to toggle attention on 3 dom elements.  On the first one I need to toggle it at 10ms past every second, on the second at 500ms past every second, on the third one at 135 ms past every second.  If I do what you suggest, then they will all toggle at the same time - which is wrong.

Comment: Yep, now I get it.

Comment: Probably off topic, but you know the reason <blink> was removed was because people didn't like it, right?

Comment: @MrLister Of course I do :) To give some context: the app is a medical monitoring system - the flashing is used when attention/intervention is really required.  This is specifically the client's requirement.